# Angular percentage mask with one decimal

Tags: regex, angular, maskedinput

i have searched a lot and i just can't find it.
I am using angular and i want a percentage mask with one decimal for an input.
So i can write like 0.1, 1.2, 10.2, 99.9%, and stops on 100%.
I don't really need the %, the important part is the number mask

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is that:

```
{{a | percent:'1.0-1'}}
```

For an input field:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="a | percent:'1.0-1'" />
```

Please take a look at the [Percent Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe)

and especially the `digitsInfo` parameter in order to achieve the desired output.

Also find [Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) if this is what you actually loking for.

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pizvsz)

Comment: But how can i set it into a input element? For example in my case i have this input 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlPercentual" formControlName="vlPercentual" name="vlPercentual"> and then when the user writes a value he can't write any value outside of the mask definition

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any reproducible example to check for any mistakes? Take a look at my working example as well.

Comment: Well, i actually did it without any mask... i used the Angular (input)  event and everytime a person types a number with 3 characters i divide it by 10. And then i handle the cases like if it starts with 100 then its 100, etc...
But i am really amazed i could not find any component or anything with an input for percentage. 
Thanks for the help anyway.